# what is the best way to compress and reduce the size of an image when uploaded to the application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

i am working on a MERN stack application and was able to handle image upload with dropzone and redux-form in the front-end and multer in the back-end and now i want to decrease the size of images without loosing quality when they surpass a max size of 4 MB and how do i test if its working . what are the most efficient tools to do this .

i've tried react image file resizer but didn't work

```
fileChangedHandler(event) {
    var fileInput = false
    if (event.target.files[0]) {
      fileInput = true
    }
    if (fileInput) {
      Resizer.imageFileResizer(
        event.target.files[0],
        100,
        100,
        'JPEG',
        100,
        0,
        uri => {
          console.log(uri)
        },
        'base64'
      );
    }
  }
```

used this fileChangeHandler method inside the dropzone tag (onChange=fileChangeHandler) and inside a redux Field component that calls the dropzone .

i didn't notice changes .

Comment: what do you mean "reduce size without losing quality"? If you mean "reduce the _file_ size without affecting quality" then you're on your own: experiment with the various image formats (png, jpg, webp, etc) and their settings to figure out what, on average, leads to the best overall size reduction for the type of images people upload. There are too many details that go into which works best to ask anyone to recommend what to do without your actual catalog of images (not "a single image", "many images")

Comment: There's no point in doing this for JPEG and PNG, these formats already apply compression when the files are created. Zipping or tar-ing them further doesn't reduce the size significantly afaik. Probably not worth it to spend computing time on this. TIFF might be a different story, but even this format allows compression.

If you have a hard constraint with the file size, you need to look into reducing the resolution of the image (scaling it down) or other lossy operations (e.g. reducing color depth).

Comment: @timotgl i have JPEG files of 14 MB in size and i think uploading many would cripple the app thats why i wanted to ask whats the best way to like down size them to around 4MB or less

Comment: @MohamedAljane Try https://github.com/lovell/sharp to downsize them. Maybe reject uploads over a certain size, so users don't upload overly huge files.